# How to migrate exchange 2007 (sherweb) to Google Apps?

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007, g-suite, migration

I need to migrate our Sherweb.com exchange 2007 services to a Google Apps account. For the process I am really not sure..

I understand I should start with creating aliases for all email accounts within the exchange server, in Google Apps, and here I'm not sure how am I supposed to explain the Exchange that the DNS have changed without losing emails.''

Second thing is: How can I safely move the up-to 3GB mailboxes from the Exchange server to the new Google Apps accounts? Must it be with Outlook data files? If so, how do I actually upload the data files into the Google Apps account? And if not, what would be a proper way to do so?

Would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Have you read the [Exchange Migration Tool's docs](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/exchangemigration)?  Will you be using the [Google Directory Sync Tool](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106368) for synchronizing your users? Where exactly are you in your [Google Apps Deployment plan](http://deployment.googleapps.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

When you launch a new Google Apps account, an "shadow" domain is being created, that serves as an alias for the account's domain. For each user email address, there's also a nick address under that domain. So you should point your Exchange server to that nick address. No need for DNS change.

For the migration task, use [Google Apps Migration for Microsoft® Exchange (AKA GAMME)](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/exchangemigration).

Answer (score 0):

USE IMAP! :-)

They split their accounts in to pods, and have no gateway (E.g. autodiscover.ihostexchange.net)

http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/what-imap-settings-to-use-exchange-2010

Comment: More detail would improve this.